# Probability proof. Check my answer?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be events defined on a sample space $\Omega$. Prove that

$$\textbf{P}(A \cap B) \geq\ 1 - \textbf{P}(A^{c})- \textbf{P}(B^{c}) $$

Answer:

\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cap B) & = \textbf{P}(A)\textbf{P}(B) \\
& = (1 - \textbf{P}(A^{c}))(1 - \textbf{P}(B^{c})) \\
& = 1 - \textbf{P}(A^{c}) - \textbf{P}(B^{c}) + \textbf{P}(A^{c})\textbf{P}(B^{c}) \geq  1 - \textbf{P}(A^{c}) - \textbf{P}(B^{c})  
\end{align*}

Comment: $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are numbers. How do you define $P(A)\cap P(B)$?

Comment: Indeed as user ajotatxe remarks: already in the first line, the expression “$P(A)\cap P(B)$” is meaningless since $P(\cdot)$ is a *number* and $\cap$ is a *set operation*.

Comment: You have assumed that $A$ and $B$ are independent events, but there is no need to.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

\begin{align*}
&\textbf{P}(A\cup B) \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B) \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow\\\\
& 1 - \textbf{P}(A^{c}) + 1 - \textbf{P}(B^{c}) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B) \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow\\\\
& 1 - \textbf{P}(A^{c}) - \textbf{P}(B^{c}) \leq \textbf{P}(A\cap B)
\end{align*}

Where we have used the following properties
\begin{cases}
\textbf{P}(X) \leq 1\\\\
\textbf{P}(X) = 1 - \textbf{P}(X^{c})\\\\
\textbf{P}(X\cup Y)  = \textbf{P}(X) + \textbf{P}(Y) - \textbf{P}(X\cap Y)
\end{cases}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $P(S^c)=1-P(S)$ and $P(A\cup B)\le 1$ therefore$$P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\le 1\\P(A)+P(B)-1\le P(A\cap B)\\P(A)+P(B)-1-1+1\le P(A\cap B)\\-P(A^c)-P(B^c)+1\le P(A\cap B)$$and finally by rearranging the terms $$P(A\cap B)\ge 1-P(A^c)-P(B^c)$$with the equality if and only if $$A\cup B=S$$

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:
   $$ \textbf{P}(A\cap B) = \textbf{P}(A)\textbf{P}(B) $$
I claim this is wrong. Suppose that we are flipping a fair coin. Let $A$ be the event the
coin comes up heads. Let $B$ be the event the coin comes up heads.  This give us:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A) &= \frac{1}{2} \\
\textbf{P}(B) &= \frac{1}{2} \\
\textbf{P}(A\cap B) &= \frac{1}{2} \\
\textbf{P}(A)\textbf{P}(B) &= \frac{1}{4} \\
\end{align*}
Hence their is a contradiction and your original statement is wrong.

I hope this helps.

Bob